# NO COLD WATER after installing pump. Have to run hot water to get cold water

Tags: plumbing

I installed pump and I am getting hot water at all faucets. My problem is contrary to why I installed pump. I now have to run and waste HOT water to get cold water. I have misplaced or lost my installation instruction paper. I feel like it may have been something in that paper that would have helped me correct that issue.Any help you can send my way will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi James, please take the tour so you'll know how to best participate here.

Comment: For us to help you, we'll need a lot more information.   What changed, why did you do it? Diagrams and pictures help as well as specifics such as make/model of pump, etc.

Comment: did you take a picture or draw a diagram of the pipework **before** you started and identify the function of each pipe?

Answer (score 1):

If the pump you installed was one that is located at the "point of use", when the pump runs it pulls water up the hot supply and pushes it back down the cold supply. I do not like this type of system since the result is something similar to what you are experiencing. Your only recourse is to make sure that the pump shuts off before the hot or warm water is pushed into the cold supply pipe. You may need to change the setting of the temperature sensing control to prevent this. You may need to play with the adjustments to get the best results. As I said earlier, these type pumps are a pain in the a## and sometimes are more trouble than they are worth.